# DatabaseTransactions after each test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test my Laravel system using the DatabaseTransactions trait. The problem is that it rollback the transaction only after all tests on a TestCase were ran. Is it possible to have a fresh database instance for every test in a TestCase?

This test case sometimes return all green but sometimes not. When it executes the test as they are wrote everything goes OK but when the order is reversed the first one fails because one Lead was created previously. What can I do?

```
public function testPotentialLeads()
{
    factory(Lead::class)->create(['lead_type' => LeadType::POTENTIAL]);
    factory(Lead::class)->create();
    factory(Lead::class)->create();

    $potential_leads = Lead::potentials()->get();

    $this->assertEquals(1, $potential_leads->count());
    $this->assertEquals(3, Lead::all()->count());
}

public function testAnotherLeadFunction()
{
    $lead = factory(Lead::class)->create();

    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

Comment: you can use the `setUp()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. It was failing because when I was doing this:

```
factory(Lead::class)->create(['lead_type' => LeadType::POTENTIAL]);
factory(Lead::class)->create();
factory(Lead::class)->create();

$potential_leads = Lead::potentials()->get();

$this->assertEquals(1, $potential_leads->count());
$this->assertEquals(3, Lead::all()->count());
```

Two Leads were being generated with randomly LeadType (through the model factory) so there were some attempts when more potential leads were created.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, this test isnt really a test: `$this->assertTrue(true);`. If you wanted to test whether the lead was created, you should have used, `$this->assertTrue($lead->exists());`
2. If you want to run unit tests in a certain order, you can use the [@depends](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) annotation
3. The `DatabaseTransactions` trait does rollback after every test and not after all tests
4. You might want to use the `DatabaseMigrations` trait if you want to migrate and migrate rollback before and after every test rather than wrap them into transactions
5. If you want to use custom setup and teardown methods, use the `afterApplicationCreated` and `beforeApplicationDestroyed` methods instead to register callbacks

Comment: 1. I know. I wrote a dummy test just to see what happens. 3. So why the tests sometimes returns true and sometimes false?